# "Couldn't match expected type" error

Tags: haskell, match

Here is my code:

```
xandy :: Element_w_Coord Cell -> Coord
xandy (e, (x, y)) = (x, y)

transition_world :: Ordered_Lists_2D Cell -> Element_w_Coord Cell -> Ordered_Lists_2D Cell
transition_world world (cell, (x, y)) = case (cell, (x, y)) of
    (Head, (x, y))-> map_Ordered_Lists_2D Tail world
    (Tail, (x, y)) -> map_Ordered_Lists_2D Conductor world
    (Empty, (x, y)) -> map_Ordered_Lists_2D Empty world
    (Conductor, (x, y))  -> map_Ordered_Lists_2D Head world
```

And here is the error message:

```
Sources/Transitions/For_Ordered_Lists_2D.hs:33:43:
    Couldn't match expected type `Element_w_Coord e0 -> Cell'
                with actual type `Cell'
    In the first argument of `map_Ordered_Lists_2D', namely `Tail'
    In the expression: map_Ordered_Lists_2D Tail world
    In a case alternative:
        (Head, (x, y)) -> map_Ordered_Lists_2D Tail world
```

Anyone likes to tell me what's wrong with my code pls?

Btw, here is the definition for

```
type Ordered_Lists_2D e = [Sparse_Line e]

data Sparse_Line e = Sparse_Line {y_pos :: Y_Coord, entries :: Placed_Elements e}

data Placed_Element  e = Placed_Element {x_pos :: X_Coord, entry :: e}
type Placed_Elements e = [Placed_Element e]


map_Ordered_Lists_2D :: (Element_w_Coord e -> b) -> Ordered_Lists_2D e -> Ordered_Lists_2D b
map_Ordered_Lists_2D f world =  case world of
   l: ls -> map_line f l: map_Ordered_Lists_2D f ls
   []    -> []
   where
      map_line :: (Element_w_Coord e -> b) -> Sparse_Line e -> Sparse_Line b
      map_line f line = Sparse_Line {y_pos = (y_pos line), entries = map_elements f (y_pos line) (entries line)}

         where
            map_elements :: (Element_w_Coord e -> b) -> Y_Coord -> Placed_Elements e -> Placed_Elements b
            map_elements f y elements = case elements of
               c: cs -> Placed_Element {x_pos = (x_pos c), entry = f ((entry c), ((x_pos c), y))}: map_elements f y cs
               []    -> []
```

Thanks for anyone who can good me some advice  XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `map_Ordered_Lists_2D` is expected to be a function, but you are passing it `Tail`, which is of type `Cell`.

The following will type-check and should help you as a starting point:

```
transition_world world (cell, (x, y)) = case (cell, (x, y)) of
    (Head, (x, y))-> map_Ordered_Lists_2D (const Tail) world
    (Tail, (x, y)) -> map_Ordered_Lists_2D (const Conductor) world
    (Empty, (x, y)) -> map_Ordered_Lists_2D (const Empty) world
    (Conductor, (x, y))  -> map_Ordered_Lists_2D (const Head) world
```

(The function `const` takes a value and turns it into a function that always returns that same value, regardless of its argument.)

Comment: sry man...  that place is defined for cell type... so its not working T_T

Comment: @libra What is with the response?  The man function in quetion clearly takes a function as it's first argument (`map_Ordered_Lists_2D :: (Element_w_Coord e -> b) ->  ...`) and you are clearly passing it a constructor (`map_Ordered_Lists_2D Tail`) which, while you omit the code, the compiler says is of type `Cell`.

Comment: @libra I took your exact code, and filled in a couple of gaps - `data Cell = Tail | Head | Empty | Conductor`, and a couple of deducable type-synonyms - and it compiled fine with the change I suggested. I wasn't saying this is the correct solution for your code, but the types should be correct.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, dont have a computer with linux these days, and my Mac is broken, so i cant really test with that, sry, but thx and vote anyway XD

Comment: @PeterHall , dont have a computer with linux these days, and my Mac is broken, so i cant really test with that, sry, but thx and vote anyway XD

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to make functions a bit smaller, like:

```
xandy :: Element_w_Coord Cell -> Coord
xandy (_, coord) = coord

transition_world :: Ordered_Lists_2D Cell -> Element_w_Coord Cell -> Ordered_Lists_2D Cell
transition_world world (cell, _) = map_Ordered_Lists_2D (transition_cell cell) world 
     where
        transition_cell :: Cell -> Cell
        transition_cell cell
               | Head = Tail 
               | Tail = Conductor
               | Empty = Empty
               | Conductor = Head
```

and

```
map_Ordered_Lists_2D :: (Element_w_Coord e -> b) -> Ordered_Lists_2D e -> Ordered_Lists_2D b
map_Ordered_Lists_2D f world =  map (map_line f) world
  where
    map_line :: (Element_w_Coord e -> b) -> Sparse_Line e -> Sparse_Line b
    map_line f line = Sparse_Line {y_pos = y_pos line, entries = map_elements f (y_pos line) (entries line)}
    map_elements :: (Element_w_Coord e -> b) -> Y_Coord -> Placed_Elements e -> Placed_Elements b
    map_elements f y elements = let 
            place_e c = Placed_Element {x_pos = x_pos c, entry = f (entry c, (x_pos c, y))}
          in 
            map place_e elements
```

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, dont have a computer with linux these days, and my Mac is broken, so i cant really test with that, sry, but thx and vote anyway XD